# Checking whether Queue has anything left before calling remove()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

I am using a [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) to queue elements before a set of threads processes them:

```
public class AsyncActionQueue implements Serializable {

    ...

    private Queue<QueuedAction> queue;

    public AsyncActionQueue() {

        this.queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    }

    ...

    private class QueueProcessor implements Runnable {

        private boolean isKilled = false;

        public void run() {

            while(!isKilled) {
                QueuedAction action = queue.remove();
```

I thought that `queue.remove()` would return null if there are no more elements in the queue but instead, I get a [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).

This is a situation where the queue is a singleton and an elastic number of threads can be engaged in emptying it. What is the best way for a thread to check whether there are elements in the queue before attempting a remove? Should I just check whether `queue.size() > 0`, meaning is that thread-safe?

Comment: Or you could just catch the exception?

Comment: It's a runtime exception so it's a bad habit to catch it. sort of like the NullPointer...

Comment: You can check `queue.isEmpty()` to check if the queue is empty, also you are using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` which is thread safe.

Answer (score 6):

You can either catch the exception or use `poll()` which will return `null` if empty.

Catching a `RuntimeException` is not necessarily a "bad habit" by itself, but in this case it would be unnecessary since [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) contains methods for both requirements. For removal `remove()` throws an exception, `poll()` returns null, for insertion you have `add()` and `offer()` etc.

Testing for the size before calling `remove()` wouldn't have helped either since it wouldn't have been atomi. The size could have come back as `1`, then another thread could have removed it, and this thread's `remove()` would have thrown the exception anyway.

Comment: perfect, that's what i was looking for.  essentially, `poll()` is like the `remove()` but returns null if empty

Comment: I'd argue that catching the `RuntimeException` _is_ a bad habit.  Exceptions are expensive and should be used in "exceptional" circumstances.  Your `pol()` answer is spot on.